# CodeGear Delphi For PHP - Why does readItemIndex() return -1?

Tags: php, delphi-for-php

I intend to create a dialog box by using a `Window` object (`class Window extends QWidget`).

The dialog box containing these elements:

- a listbox (`ListBox1`)
- 2 labels (`Label1` & `Label2`)
- a button

The `onClick()` function for the list box:

```
function ListBox1Click($sender, $params)
{
   $selected = $this->ListBox1->readItemIndex();
   $this->Label1->setCaption($selected); 
}
```

The purpose of this code is to select an item from the listbox, then display (`ListBox1Click`) it's index on `Label1`.

However, when an item is selected, `readItemIndex()` returns numerical value `-1.

Items contained in `ListBox1`

```
(Key / Value)
32432 / dfdfwsf
43543 / csdcsdc
```

For instance, if I select `dfdfwsf` from the listbox, it should have return the index/key `32432`; instead, `-1` is returned.